# Azure Front Door - how to custom domain with default backend host name?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an azure app service which enabled custom domain as **"www.mysite.com"**, we would like to set up a web application firewall on front door to protect slow read http attack.

After setting up Azure Front Door, my front end host is shown as **"mysite.azurefd.net"**, and the issue of slow read http attack was gone, which is perfect!

But the new problem is, we want to custom front end host to **"www.mysite.com"** which eventually forwards/redirects to app service with the same domain name, not the default **"mysite.azurefd.net"**. Because i always want user goes through front door to delivery request to my Azure app service

Is this doable?

Answer (score 1):

> But the new problem is, we want to custom front end host to
>   "www.mysite.com" which eventually forwards/redirects to app service
>   with the same domain name, not the default "mysite.azurefd.net".

You can add a custom name to your Azure front door frontend host name but you can not add `the same domain name` as the custom domain in your app service as **A CNAME record is not allowed to coexist with any other data** from [RFC1912](http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912.txt) section 2.4

In this case, you have to add a different domain like `sub.mysite.com` as the frontend host to your Azure front door like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/front-door-custom-domain), then add or update an existing routing rule that map frontend hosts `sub.mysite.com` with your path like `/*` to your existing backend pool of web app.